# Is it wise to use HOTP (raw bytes) as a key for HMAC?

Tags: protocol-design, hmac, mac, hotp

Assume I have client and server applications with a shared master secret `KEY_SECRET` already in place. Also assume that the client and server have an implicit shared counter `CTR` initialized on the same value.

Is it wise to sign the data sent from the client to the server in a following way:

```
KEY_SIGN = HOTP(KEY_SECRET, CTR)
SIGNATURE = HMAC_SHA256(DATA, KEY_SIGN)
```

Client is technically able to compute the signature and server is able to validate it but I am wondering if this could have some hidden security / crypto / math side-effects.

Note: I assume "raw" HOTP format (4 bytes) here, not the decimalized version with the final "modulo D" that gives away the D-digit numeric code.

Note 2 (edit): As suggested in the comments below, using simply `KEY_SIGN = HMAC_SHA1(KEY_SECRET, CTR)` would gain much better key entropy.

Comment: You're using a 4-byte (32 bit) value as your key for HMAC (trivially brute-force able on home computers). I'd avoid that if possible although your construction *may* prevent attacks with better than $2^{-32}$ success probability.

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right - I am trying too hard to find some "straightforward building blocks". Instead of doing what I just wrote above, I could include CTR in DATA and use HMAC directly, as such: SIGNATURE = HMAC_SHA256(KEY_SECRET, COMBINE(DATA, CTR)), or alternatively, I could strip HOTP down one step further to simply use HMAC to derive N-th KEY_SECRET - that way I would at least keep reasonable entropy (since I would lose the TRUNCATE step).

Comment: If you'd strip the TRUNCATE step it should be reasonably secure. I suggest editing this into your question.

Comment: I edited your tags, because by signatures we usually mean public-key signatures. What you are using is a MAC.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by SEJPM in the comments, four bytes is much too short for an HMAC key.

Since `KEY_SECRET` is already in place, you could just use it directly as a MAC key, but then you need to make sure that `DATA` cannot collide with any counter value. You could do this by prefixing `DATA` with enough constant values to make it longer than the counter.

For example: `MAC = HMAC(KEY_SECRET, 0x01 * 9 || DATA`, where nine `1`-bytes are prepended to make it longer than the eight-byte counter of HOTP.